# The head of text string is cut on android compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an android app using the Jetpack Compose.

I found a bug(?) related with the `Text`.

I used the `TextOverflow` to handle long length string.

```kotlin
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
        .requiredWidthIn(max = 184.dp),
    text = longText,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
    maxLines = 1,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
)
```

It shows like below:
[image]

The front character is cut.
Why? and How solve this?

Comment: looks like a bug indeed, I suggest you [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of using `requiredWidthIn`, using `widthIn` will do.